# What your preferred workflow for creating data for print, web and presentations an efficient way?

Tags: presentations, workflow

I'm writing a businessplan in LaTeX including tables and graphs. From the paper I'm creating presentations in reveal.js, and later some of the informasjon will go on website. I can't help but feel that recreating latex tabels and graphs in HTML, and having to update the data several places, is inefficient.

So I have looked at alternatives. [Creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole_(markup)) which says it can convert to e.g. HTML and Latex. But it seems like a dead project not really supported by anyone.

What your preferred workflow for creating data for print, web and presentations an efficient way?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: you can try `tex4ht` for conversion to HTML, although expect that you will need to write lot of custom configurations if you want something fancy. search this site for `tex4ht` tag for some examples of the conversion and see [my tutorial](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial)

Comment: If the LaTeX code you're using isn't particularly complex, maybe start with [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) and convert it to [HTML, LaTeX](http://pandoc.org/demo/example9/description.html#using-pandoc), and [reveal.js](http://pandoc.org/demo/example9/producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc.html) as required?

Comment: Thanks! [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) seems similar to Pandoc. So there's 3 possibilities - how would you rate these three for continuous development?

Comment: You can google comparisons between Markdown and ReST, but [Pandoc Markdown and ReST Compared](http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/doc-notes/markdown-and-rest-compared.html) shows syntax differences between Pandoc and ReST specifically. I don't see an obvious way to get from ReST to reveal.js, but I'm sure you've already figured that out. ReST has better support for multi-file documents, but that can be worked around in Pandoc.